# How to View the preview zip files list in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

so.I Made a System to check “PCB” File ,i got six File in .zip file,
I Want to Upload the .zip file to my service,
how to make sure that the six file is the one i want~?
i want to get a files list before i upload the zip file...

Comment: how can i do.? i using asp.net c#

Comment: http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [dotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) Library, it's open source and very easy to use, here is a example of listing files inside of zip file that is uploaded with ASP.NET FileUpload control:

```
  if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
  {
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(FileUpload1.FileContent))
    {
      foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip)
      {
        if (entry.IsDirectory)
          Response.Write("Directory: ");
        else
          Response.Write("File : ");
        Response.Write(entry.FileName + "<br /><br />");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: i got anhoter other what's header ?

Comment: so..thank u very much..?it's real read the zip file, or unzip the file,and read the files? and thank u very much bakual

Comment: not sure that I understud you, but this example just enumerates contents of zip file, nothing more.